# Can we make `.at()` (or defining another function of simlar functionality) return type of literal tuples depend on its boundary

Tags: typescript

For literal tuples, is there a way to make the return type of `.at()` (or another function with a similar functionality) depend on the length of the tuple? Specifically, when given a literal number, `.at()` should be able to tell whether the return type is undefined or not.

For example,

```
const myArray = [1, 2, 3] as const;
myArray[2] + 10;   // OK
myArray[3];  // Tuple type 'readonly [1, 2, 3]' of length '3' has no element at index '3'.
myArray[myArray.length - 100];  // Out of boundary but no error.

myArray.at(-1) + 10;     // OBject is possibly 'undefined'.
```

(Seems like neither `[]` nor `.at()` is capable of a full out-of-boundary check even though the index is computable at compilation time.)

See [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUEMEwLwwNoCMANDAEwkDMAujOhDKJFANwBQiqGCepNA1DAIAGZjDEB6cTADyAaXbI0mPNVExJMACoBXAA4AbAKYwoCXcYDkKQ+gAm4fVkIlyMahZggAZjCNgA5lAAFjAWFB5BdDBgIDCGRnCGYLDosACWYLaGAB6h4QB0CpzKHEoI+X6BIQC0gkJCVGoa0tqw3jAARiDamegoWB2t0bGGaCAohUVl+akAFNUEAJQwAsJqYupS0gBCAFaGwOn0uiAQEGkdjqE9WV4ZhrYW+UA).

Comment: See the linked q/a for a discussion of this and the (limited) options available.